# Unable to parse JSON response string to XML

Tags: c#, .net, json, xml, asp.net-web-api

my web service is giving json string formatted to XML using object to XMl serializer. my reponse is like :

```
public static string ObjectToXmlString(this Object obj)
    {
        string xmlStr = string.Empty;
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
            {
                Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                Indent = false,
                OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
                NewLineChars = string.Empty,
                NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None
            };
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, settings))
            {
                xs.Serialize(writer, obj,ns);
            }
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()).Replace("\"", string.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Service Response:

```
 "﻿<ArrayOfOwnerShipDetails><OwnerShipDetails><OwnerShipId>80932</OwnerShipId><FileNumber>rp1144</FileNumber><Salutation>Mr</Salutation><OwnerFirstName>Jai Kumar Datwni ji</OwnerFirstName><OwnerMiddleName /><OwnerLastName /><ResidentialAddress>1159 Sec 18 C,c Hd</ResidentialAddress><EmailID /><MobileNumber /><VoterID /><AadharCardNo /><RelationCode>S</RelationCode><RelationDescription>Son of</RelationDescription><FatherOrHusbandName>Lachman Dass S</FatherOrHusbandName><PropertyShareInPercentage>50.00</PropertyShareInPercentage><AdditionalRemarks /></OwnerShipDetails></ArrayOfOwnerShipDetails>"
```

But when i try to parse this json response to other application where i am calling my service.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
                    var response = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:50429/api/Haris/GetOwnersByFileNo?fileNo=RP1144").Result;

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // by calling .Result you are performing a synchronous call
                        var responseContent = response.Content;

                        // by calling .Result you are synchronously reading the result
                        string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Trim();


                        // Create the XmlDocument.
                        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                        **doc.LoadXml(responseString ); ---> Error Comes here**


                    }
                }
```

it gives error 
**Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1**

But if i copy same reponse to notepad and then paste to variable at run time it works fine. Is there anything wrong with double quotes coming in json string.

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Load()` method instead, it'll solve the problem. [See more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Otherwise**

```
doc.LoadXml(responsestring.Substring(responsestring.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine)));
```

[Live Demo](http://rextester.com/VBXY33368)

Comment: I have tried this but both gives error: .Load() gives --- >Illegal characters in path. and responsestring.Substring(responsestring.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) gives ----> {"StartIndex cannot be less than zero.\r\nParameter name: startIndex"}

Comment: use @ before your xml while load.

Comment: before xml string that i am passing to .Load() ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got solution by converting string to steam and again to string:

```
 string sb = responseString;
                         sb = responseString.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Trim().ToString().Trim();
                         var a = GenerateStreamFromString(sb);
                         StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(a);
                         string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                        doc.LoadXml(responseString);
```

After this i found this solution, which fitted perfectly :
POST : [How do I prevent ReadAsStringAsync returning a doubly escaped string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790588/how-do-i-prevent-readasstringasync-returning-a-doubly-escaped-string)